# PHP unset not removing value from array loop

Tags: php, unset

I have an `array("https", "www", "stackoverflow", "com")`

```
$search_array = array("https", "www", "stackoverflow", "com");

for ($i=0; $i < count($search_array); $i++) { 
    if (
        $search_array[$i] == null ||
        strtolower($search_array[$i]) == "http" && count($search_array) > 1 ||
        strtolower($search_array[$i]) == "https" && count($search_array) > 1 ||
        strtolower($search_array[$i]) == "www" && count($search_array) > 1 ||
        strtolower($search_array[$i]) == "com" && count($search_array) > 1
    ) unset($search_array[$i]);
}

die(print_r($search_array));
```

I want the result `array("stackoverflow");`, but im getting the result `array("stackoverflow", "com");` any idea?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? That's so little code that you should be able to dump the values in each iteration and check them

Comment: @NicoHaase Its not removing the "com" from the array even tho i belive the code is correct?

Comment: This isn't a solution per-se, but your code works perfect when using a `foreach()` instead of a `for()` loop: `foreach($search_array as $i => $domain) {` (https://3v4l.org/41FYo for reference)

Comment: @TimLewis thanks for your solution, you should submit it as a awnser!

Comment: I mean, I can, but using a different syntax isn't really a solution; don't you want to know why your original code wasn't working?

Comment: @TimLewis i have realised its down to the `count($search_array)`, the count will go down in each for loop. thanks

Comment: There you go  I will post my answer as an alternative

Comment: Yeah exactly, the count goes down and iteration stops. `$c = count($search_array); for ($i=0; $i < $c; $i++) {`. Just do the count before the loop. (Also, in general a good idea to avoid functions in a loop condition, waste of cycles to re-evaluate at each loop.)

Comment: All those conditionals inside the if statement should be grouped imo. at least for clarity, also that may be causing problems and the goal  it's not clear. What I mean is: e.g. `$search_array[$i] == null ||
        (strtolower($search_array[$i]) == "http" && count($search_array) > 1) ||
        (strtolower($search_array[$i]) == "https" && count($search_array) > 1)` grouping with parenthesis

Comment: If you look at it as the difference between 2 arrays `$remove = ['http', 'https', 'www', 'com'];
print_r(array_diff($search_array, $remove));`

Comment: @MarkusAO: Your solution also wouldn't work, as on the third iteration $search_array[2] is undefined (as the array was truncated with unset twice before)

Comment: @fseydel tested and working. Even a zero-indexed array is not automatically reindexed by `unset` of one of its members. Only the `count` changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments and other answers, you have an issue when looping and `unset()`-ing. The answers show how to handle this when using a `for()` loop, but you can also simply use a `foreach()`:

```
$search_array = array("https", "www", "stackoverflow", "com");

foreach($search_array as $i => $domain) { 
    if (
        $domain == null ||
        $domain == "http" && count($search_array) > 1 ||
        $domain == "https" && count($search_array) > 1 ||
        $domain == "www" && count($search_array) > 1 ||
        $domain == "com" && count($search_array) > 1
    ) { 
        unset($search_array[$i]);
    }
}

die(print_r($search_array));
```

Output from this approach is:

> Array
> (
> [2] => stackoverflow
> )

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying the array while looping around it. This causes the for loop to not run for all of the elements inside it. You can verify this by calling `echo $i` where you currently do `unset()`.

Also your if statements need brackets around them to ensure that the `&&` and `||` run in the correct order.

To get the result you want, create a new array of the valid values that you want to save:

```
<?php
$search_array = array("https", "www", "stackoverflow", "com");
$result_array = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($search_array); $i++) {
    $item = strtolower($search_array[$i]);
    
    if (
        isset($search_array[$i])
        && $item !== "http"
        && $item !== "https"
        && $item !== "www"
        && $item !== "com"
    ) {
        $result_array[] = $item;
    }
}


var_dump($result_array);   // Result => "stackoverflow"
```

Answer (score 1):

You're changing the value of your loop exit condition inside your loop - which is usually a bad idea.
On unsetting the array value, the array length gets lower, and thus the last iteration is never run.

first run (after unset):
$i=0; $search_array = array("www", "stackoverflow", "com"); count($search_array)=3

second run (after unset):
$i=1; $search_array = array("stackoverflow", "com"); count($search_array)=2

now your loop won't run again, as next $i would be 2, and this is now triggering your exit condition...

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what others here correctly point out and demonstrate I would like to suggest to take a somewhat more direct approach: always use the right tool for your task.

What you are trying to do is filter the input array, right? Then why don't you use the `array_filter()` function which does exactly that?

```
<?php
print_r(
    array_filter(
        ["https", "www", "stackoverflow", "com"], 
        function($value) {
            return !in_array($value, ["https", "www", "com"]);
        }
    )
);
```

The output obviously is:

> Array
> (
> [2] => stackoverflow
> )

Comment: Would `array_diff()` be a better tool?

Comment: @NigelRen Also an alternative, there is no yes or no for that. It depends on the actual task the OP faces. The code in the OPs question obviously is just a demonstration, not the real task. `array_filter()` offers much more flexibility. Just think of case insensivity and trimming for example.

Answer (score 0):

Think I might be late, but this is happening because you were modifying the original array. A much more cleaner way of doing this would be as follows:

```php
<?php

$search_array = array("https", "www", "stackoverflow", "com");

for ($i=count($search_array)-1; $i>=0; $i--) { 
    if ( in_array(strtolower($search_array[$i]), ["https", "www", "com"]) )
        unset($search_array[$i]);
}

echo print_r($search_array, true);
```